# Why is my sent email delayed 30 seconds?

Tags: dns, apple-mail

Why is my sent email delayed 30 seconds? Suspect DNS server.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? What version of MacOSX, what MacBook, what wireless router, etc?

Comment: Define what you mean by delayed. It could be a grey-listing issue, it could be batched email processing, it could be a lot of things really.

Comment: Hi digitxp, Using OS X 10.6.4, 2008 iMac, no wireless router, just a cable modem. I agree could be a grey-listing issue. Will investigate. ISP has checked its settings. Cable guy looked around the house and replaced a splitter resulting in no change in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Some email companies use to send emails in batches, so maybe every 5 minutes they send all emails, that were 'sent' in those last 5 minutes, or here 30 seconds. 
But almost no one does that anymore

gmail was a way to undo send, if the feature is enabled, where it just waits, 3 to 30 seconds, before sending the email. In that time you can hit a cancel button if you realized you've made a mistake.

Whats the domain (@applemail.com or what?), the mail client your using, are you sending the email to yourself, and anything you can tell us about your setup that might be buggered.

Comment: Thanks alpha1, domain is comline.com, using Apple Mail POP, sending to myself and others. Consulted with Apple Genius who deleted a preference file resulting in normal behavior in the Apple Store. Fail back home. The research continues. Current hypothese is fault in our ISP/street network cabling or some 'policy' setting in postfix.

Comment: ok, so then try using a proxy or logging into your email somewhere else, like a library or work, and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks alpha1, situation remains unchanged. Discovered no postfix policy setting that would cause slow smtp response. I agree trying other locations can be useful. Meanwhile, I may change DNS settings using OpenDNS and Google's DNS set. Our ISP may have a firewall set.

Comment: Your ISP should have to tell you if they do, so give them a call as ask their policy on it all.

Comment: We are in contact with our ISP and they are searching for an answer. If a solution is found, I will post.